# Centering a span tag in Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, margins

I've set up a media query that should center an image when the screen is smaller than 600px. When bigger then 600px, the image correctly displays to the right of the site title. Chrome inspector assures me that the queries are working, but I think there might be an overarching rule that's keeping my margin: auto from applying. The 'globes' image in question is at the top of:

http://livinginbetween.org/temp/

I'd love any suggestions. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Please post the HTML. we should not have to go to an external website to solve your problem. See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from more details

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: block;` to your media query to center the image.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 599px) and (min-width: 0px) {
  .globes {
    display: block;
    width: 159px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  }
}
```